# How to show that $f(x,y,\mu\mid a,b,\Sigma) = f(x,y\mid \mu, a,b,\Sigma)\cdot p(\mu)$ if $(x,y)$ are MVN and $a,b,\Sigma$ are hyperparameters?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose that $x,y$ are multivariate Normal:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal N\left(\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix},\Sigma\right)
$$
and $v = a + bu$ with some parameters ($a,b)$ and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal covariance matrix.

Assume that the value $u$ follows a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\tau^2$.

My question is why it is the case that:

\begin{align*}
f(x,y,\mu\mid a,b,\Sigma) &= f(x,y\mid \mu, a,b,\Sigma)\cdot p(\mu) \\
\end{align*}

It seems that factoring $f(x,y\mid \mu, a,b,\Sigma)$ apart yields:

$$
f(x,y\mid \mu, a,b,\Sigma) = \frac{f(x,y,\mu, a,b,\Sigma)}{f(\mu, a,b,\Sigma)}
$$

and to get the result we need that $f(\mu, a,b,\Sigma) = f(\mu) \cdot f(a,b,\Sigma)$, but here $a,b,\Sigma$ are all fixed parameters that are not a distribution.

Hence, how exactly do we get the above equation of:

\begin{align*}
f(x,y,\mu\mid a,b,\Sigma) &= f(x,y\mid \mu, a,b,\Sigma)\cdot p(\mu) \text{ ?}
\end{align*}

How does the factorization work on the right side? And what does it mean to condition on parameters $(a,b,\Sigma)$ that do not have a distribution? Is it the likelihood?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is only some writing convention. As you said $a$, $b$ and $\Sigma$ are fixed, and consequently it does not mean anything to condition on them. However some authors like to put them after the $|$ sign to remind them as parameters.

But then, since $\mu$ does not seem to depend on those parameters (which is not the case of $y$ for example), you can write that $f(\mu, a, b, \Sigma)=f(\mu)$.

Or you can see it as $f(x, y, \mu | a, b, \Sigma)=f(x, y | \mu, a, b, \Sigma) \cdot f(\mu | a, b, \Sigma)$ with Bayes rule, and $f(\mu | a, b, \Sigma) = f(\mu)$ since $\mu$ does not depend on $a$, $b$ and $\Sigma$.

Comment: It appears that $f(\mu|a, b, \Sigma) = \frac{f(\mu,a, b, \Sigma)}{f(a, b, \Sigma)}$. Is it wrong to write $f(a, b, \Sigma)$? Is this a joint density for parameters (which are assumed fixed)? Is this then a joint density on point masses?

Comment: As I said, I think it is a matter of **notation**. Look for example at this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution. They write $f(x | \mu,\sigma)$ for the pdf of a normal distribution. But there is no conditioning on $\mu$ or $\sigma$! In this case I prefer writing $f(x ; \mu,\sigma)$ to avoid the confusion. Therefore writing $f(\mu | a,b, \Sigma)=\dfrac{f(\mu,a,b,\Sigma)}{f(a,b,\Sigma)}$ has no real sense (again look at this example of wikipedia). And I agree with you, this is confusing. Here $a$, $b$ and $\Sigma$ are just parameters, you don't condition on them.

Comment: oh I've just seen that you asked another question exactly on the matter of the normal distribution!